# Numpy, Pandas counterpart in .Net or .Netcore

Tags: python, ml.net

In ML.Net what are the counterparts of Numpy/ Pandas python libraries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are all the available .NET counterparts that I know of:

## Numpy

there are a few `Tensor` type proposals in dotnet/corefx:

- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25779
- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/34527

There is also an [implementation of NumPy made by the SciSharp org](https://github.com/SciSharp/NumSharp).

## Pandas

On dotnet/corefx there is a [DataFrame Discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26845) issue, which has spawned a [dotnet/corefxlab project](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/a4be93c3dff07dd55a04366a459f1776b9338666/src/Microsoft.Data/DataFrame.cs#L14) to implement a C# DataFrame library similar to Pandas.

There are also other DataFrame implementations:

- [Deedle](https://github.com/fslaborg/Deedle)
- [SciSharp Pandas.NET](https://github.com/SciSharp/Pandas.NET)

## ML.NET

In ML.NET, [IDataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.idataview) is an interface that abstracts the underlying storage for tabular data, ex. a DataFrame. It doesn't have the full rich APIs like a Pandas DataFrame does, but instead it supports reading data from any underlying source - for example a text file, SQL table, in-memory objects, etc.

<s>There currently isn't a "data exploration" API in ML.NET v1.0, like you would have with a Pandas DataFrame. The current plan is for the corefxlab `DataFrame` class to implement `IDataView`, and then you can use `DataFrame` to do the data exploration, and feed it directly into ML.NET.</s>

UPDATE: For a "data exploration" API similar to Pandas, check out the [Microsoft.Data.Analysis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Analysis/) package, which is currently in preview. It implements `IDataView` and can be fed directly into ML.NET to train or make predictions.

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly the regular .NET types + the [IDataView types](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/IDataViewTypeSystem.md). 
The document is a bit out of date.